# Getting "Caused by: WebServiceIOException I/O error: Unexpected end of file from server", although using same cert works with SOAP UI

Tags: soapui, spring-ws

I have defined the template as

```
<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <property name="messageSender">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender">
            <property name="trustManagers">
                <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.support.TrustManagersFactoryBean">
                    <property name="keyStore" ref="myTrustStore" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="keyManagers">
                <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.support.KeyManagersFactoryBean">
                    <property name="keyStore" ref="myKeyStore" />
                    <property name="password" value="${cdds.webservice.keystore_password}" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

It works fine with X certificate, but as soon as I use Y certificate it throws the below error

> Caused by: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
>   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561)
>   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
>   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383)
>   at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:373)

Root Cause exception

> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
>   
> at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:772)
>   
> at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
>   
> at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:769)
>   
> at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
>   
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1323)
>   
> at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
>   
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
>   
> at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection.getResponseCode(HttpUrlConnection.java:143)
>   
> at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.AbstractHttpSenderConnection.hasError(AbstractHttpSenderConnection.java:46)
>   
> at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTempl
> ate.hasError(WebServiceTempl
> ate.java:673)
>   
> at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTempl
> ate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTempl
> ate.java:607)
>   
> at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTempl
> ate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTempl
> ate.java:555)>

However when I am calling the same webservice via SOAP UI by setting the keystore (Y certificate) and password, it is working fine.

Not able to understand, why the code is throwing "unexpected end of file from server" for Y certificate, where as it is working via SOAP UI